# What is difference between using input#id and just #id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any reason to use for ex. input#id? Why not just #id? Code below:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    var rate = $("#rate_1").val();
    var quant = $("#quant_1").val();
});
```

VS

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    var rate = $("input#rate_1").val();
    var quant = $("input#quant_1").val();
});
```

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="textbox" id="quant_1" class="txtbox"></input></td>
    <td><input type="textbox" id="rate_1" class="txtbox"></input></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `input#id` will make the engine to first get only specific type of elements and the fetch element with necessary ID. This reduces lot of work for engine.

Comment: They are the same since you are specifying an `id` it does not matter how do you access it, I think `id` alone could be more readable.

Comment: @Rajesh I don't think there's an enormous impact on the engine since it's an id and there's only one element of it in the whole document, so it is already fast.

Comment: @Rajesh, that was my guess, but i wasn't sure :)

Comment: @Ahmad How does engine fetch element with id?

Comment: @Ahmad but if there is a looooot of code there is propably a difference I guess. Anyway, even if it have marginal impact, it propably is good practice :)

Comment: @Rajesh merely the whole document can only have one `id` so if you do `input#id` or `#id` is the same.

Comment: @Ahmad thank a lot for answers :)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the practical effect in this instance, there is no difference.

In terms of potential practical effect, `input#id` only selects elements that (a) are `input` elements and (b) have the `id` attribute set to `id`. `#id` only asks for the second check. So you are being slightly more specific. That said, if you have an `id` that could apply to multiple types of elements, you're doing something wrong.

In terms of performance effect, there is a slight difference. Behind the scenes, `#id` is found using `document.getElementById` ([source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/96533cd0e889a09ca71b90d74d71e590623cf26f/src/core/init.js#L80)). `input#id` uses `jQuery.find` and therefore ultimately `document.querySelectorAll` ([source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/96533cd0e889a09ca71b90d74d71e590623cf26f/src/core/init.js#L98)). The `getElementById` method will have marginally better performance -- but don't pay any attention to this. The gain will be so minuscule that you wouldn't notice it if it were repeated a thousand times.

The most significant difference: `input#id` is more characters to type and there is a larger chance of a typo.